# Why doesn't the selected value in a dropdown menu have the applied color on mobile devices, even though it works fine on browsers?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <div class="is-active">
      <button class="sr-btn" type="button" value="">select...</button>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="sr-list-wrapper">
        <ul class="sr-list">
          <li class="sr-list-item">
            <button class="sr-list-button is-selected" data-value="">
              <span class="is-aural">selected: </span>select...
            </button>
          </li>
          <li class="sr-list-item">
            <button class="sr-list-button" data-value="value4">value4</button>
          </li>
          ...
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And the following SCSS code:

```
&.is-active {
  .sr-btn {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

This code works fine on desktop browsers, but the selected value in the dropdown menu is not colored **red** on mobile devices.

Can anyone help me fix this?

I tried to fix adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` or `-moz-appearance: none;` but didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

```
&.is-active {
```

.sr-btn {
color: red; // for pc

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {  
  color: blue; //  mobile
}
```

}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).